# React-i18next - HTML <a> anchor href preservation

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I am forced to use the following key:

`"key": "Some Text <u><a href=https://www.example.com/>Read more</a></u>"`

Is it possible to use the above in React-i18next's `<Trans>` component, so the `href` attr is used?
Here's what I have so far:

i18next config:

```
.init({
  react: {
    transSupportBasicHtmlNodes: true,
    transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ['u', 'a']
  }
})
```

component:

```
<Trans i18nKey="key">
 Text <u><a to='link'>link</a></u>
</Trans>
```

or

```
<Trans i18nKey="key">
 Text <u><a to={t('link')}>link</a></u>
</Trans>
```

The output is missing href attribute on anchor tag:

```
"Some Text <u><a>Read more</a></u>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use interpolation while defining the key value because `transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor`  doesn't preserve the attributes.

Check [this link](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-for-less-than-br-greater-than-and-other-simple-html-elements-in-translations-v-10-4-0) for more details

`transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor` allows elements not having additional attributes like className and only no children (void) or one text child:

> - `<br/>`
> - `<strong>bold</strong>`
> - `<p>some paragraph</p>`
>
> but not:
>
> - `<i className="icon-gear" />`  // no attributes allowed
> - `<strong title="something">bold something</strong>` // no attr
> - `<bold>bold<i>italic</i></b>` // no inner elements - only strings!

For your case you would use the key

```
"key": "Some Text <1><0>Read more</0></1>"
```

and use it with Trans like

```
<Trans i18nKey="key">
 Text <u><a href="href=https://www.example.com/">link</a></u>
</Trans>
```

Keep in mind to use `href` and not `to` attribute on `anchor tag`

Check [How to get the correct translation string?](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#how-to-get-the-correct-translation-string) for writing a correct translation string

Comment: This is correct - at least the a tag should be not in transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor as it's not a basic tag -> it's a react element needing additional params set

Answer (score 0):

Change to prop to href prop. You are using html anchor tag not react router dom Link.

```
<Trans i18nKey="key">
 Text <u><a href={t('link')}>link</a></u>
</Trans>
```

Comment: While this is most def. correct - I was so hooked I didn't see that - it doesn't change the outcome